# How to check a customer has a billing or shipping address using customer id?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-address, billing-address

I am running an update on my customer list.
In this i am retrieving the customer telephone number using

```
$telephone_number =  $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

If the customer doesn't has any address there were an error message like below

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getTelephone() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/public_html/custxxxxxxxx_XXX.php on line 44

I understood that this error is coming because of the customer doesn't have any address.
so before using

```
$telephone_number =  $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

is there any way to check the customer has any address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return all customer addresses `$customer->getAddresses()` so `count($customer->getAddresses())` should return quantity of addresses of customer